# Django Admin form save same model twice

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Im trying to add a new Object to a m2m field, im using django admin and it will open a form to add the new object model. The problem is, this is just a form and the model is not created yet so its impossible to get fields of this model ( I want the primary key but it doesnt have because the object is not added to the database yet). What i want to accomplish is to save the model as soon as the form initiates and still work on the same object and when the user clicks SAVE button it will update the object saved and not create a new one.

```
class PrecoPorEpocaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Preco_por_epoca
        fields = ('epoca',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrecoPorEpocaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.save()
        print self.instance.pk
```

Calling self.instance.save() will add the object to the data base when the form is initialized but when adding the form it will create a new object because im not working on that instance anymore. I've tried to override with the save(commit=False) but it doesnt solve the problem because it doesnt add the object to the database thus im not able to get the primary key of the object. Im stuck in this for 2 days trying to figure a solution, im fairly new to Django. I can provide more code if needed, thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need primary key? How are you opening the form to add the new object model?

Comment: self.isntance.save() , spelling mistake.

Comment: The spelling mistake was added just here by mistake

Comment: Im opening the form in django admin (+) add object on a m2m field. 
I want the primary key to filter one field of the form